# Not able to run batch script(.bat file) in Jenkins client machine

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

In my Java program I am launching batch script(.bat file).
I am facing following error:

```
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "C:\..\Project_Name"): CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1148)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1113)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to VM1(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:220)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:928)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:95)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1148)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1113)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have made Jenkins service as Windows service and tried with providing administrator privileges to the service. [I have changed Jenkins Client service properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpNbV.jpg) But I am facing the same error.
Following are the ways I am launching my batch script:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\file1.bat"));
```

and

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:\\file1.bat");
```

or

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\file1.bat");
```

In my case all client machines are windows machies.
Please anyone tell me how to solve this.

Comment: I had similar issue and tried multiple ways to execute a cmd bat file in my linux jenkins. :D Just thought of sharing it here! Yeah! It took me few hours to realize that! so embarrassing!

Answer (score 1):

Check the log
"C:\..\Project_Name"

This directory is invalid...

So in addition you should avoid the root directory "C:\"  wich is protected by windows.

Try to work with the current directory (should be the job workspace).